# junit and ant issue. Cannot start test

Tags: ant, junit

When I am running a junit test from ant I always get:

```
D:\metrike>ant test
Buildfile: build.xml

init:

compile:

test:
    [junit] Running jmt.test.TestCodeBase
    [junit] Testsuite: jmt.test.TestCodeBase
    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 0,046 sec
    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 0,046 sec
    [junit]
    [junit] Testcase: warning(junit.framework.TestSuite$1):     FAILED
    [junit] No tests found in jmt.test.TestCodeBase
    [junit] junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: No tests found in jmt.test.TestCodeBase
    [junit]
    [junit]
    [junit] Test jmt.test.TestCodeBase FAILED
```

This is the ant file:

```
<target name="test" depends="compile">
    <mkdir dir="target/test-results"/>
    <junit haltonfailure="no" printsummary="on">
        <classpath >
            <pathelement location="target/classes"/>
            <pathelement location="Libraries/junit3.8.1/junit.jar"/>
        </classpath>
        <formatter type="brief" usefile="false"/>
        <formatter type="xml" />
        <batchtest todir="target/test-results" >
            <fileset dir="target/classes" includes="**/TestCodeBase.class"/>
        </batchtest>
    </junit>
</target>
```

But when I manually run the test, junit test works:

```
D:\metrike>cd target

D:\metrike\target>cd classes

D:\metrike\target\classes>java jmt.test.TestCodeBase
fatsource.jar eclapsed : 2297 ms
over all : 2297 ms
contains 3073 classes and 3700 referred classes, 35968 referred methods, 22351 referred fields
Memory usage: 21326 KB
Post gc-memory usage: 19506 KB
contains 3073 classes and 3700 referred classes, 35968 referred methods, 22351 referred fields
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? I have been trying to fix this for a whole day but I cannot find the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1)  Does jmt.test.TestCodeBase extend TestCase (junit.framework.TestCase)?

If not, it will need to to be picked up by the junit ant task.

2)  Is the class written as a junit TestCase, or is it just called from the main method?  See [this link](http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/testinfected/testing.htm) for an example of writing simple tests in Junit3 style.  For Junit4, just add @Test above the methods.

3)  Are the test methods in Junit3 style (every method starts with test) or Junit4 style (every method has a @Test above it)?

If Junit3, you should be good to go.  If Junit4, you need to include the Junit4 test library in your ant classpath, rather than using junit3.8.1.

Comment: If I want to use jUnit 4, which classpath do I have to extend? The `ANT_HOME` in shell or `<classpath>` inside `<junit>` in `build.xml`?

Answer (score 1):

It seems your test class is not actually a JUnit test class. When you run it manually, you are not running it as a test, but as a regular Java application. The class has a main method, right? To run as a JUnit 3 (which you seem to be using) test, the class needs to extend TestCase and have one or more public void methods whose names start with 'test'. For testing, I would try running the class as a JUnit test in the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Please post sample code of jmt.test.TestCodeBase, esp. class definition and one of the test methods.

I looks like you use `public static int main()` instead of JUnit convention `public void testFoo()` methods. If you're using JUnit4, your test methods should have the `@Test` annotation.

JUnit tests usually cannot be run just with `java <Testclass>`